# How to create setup.exe file for window form application in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

[image][image]I created one window form application in visual studio 2019. Now I can't find any solution regarding how to create installer for that window form application.

Comment: The same way you do it in previous versions.  Copy/paste the title of your question into the Google search box to [find it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects).

Comment: in visual studio 2017 i follow this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/how-to-create-a-setup-of-windows-application-in-net/

Comment: is there any step by step procedure for 2019?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Visual Studio Installer (look @Hans Passant comment for the download).

I will make a simple tutorial:

1 - Right click on Solution of your project > Add > New Project > Write on SearchBar "Setup" > Setup Project > Next > Create;

[image]

2 - Application Folder > Add > Project Output > Primary Output;

3 - User's Desktop > Create New Shortcut to Primary Output;

4 - Rename your Shortcut for the name of your App;

5 - User's Program Menu > Create New Shortcut to Primary Output;

6 - Rename your Shortcut for the name of your App;

7 - Application Folder > Add all the files needed for the operation of the application.

Good points:

- Don't forget to put the icons on your application folder.
- When you edit your application you have to build your setup or the setup will be with the previous "version".
- Don't forget to edit the properties of setup (Who created the application, version...).

Comment: i couldn't find SetupProject under projectTypesOther.

Comment: there was no option listed when i serach setup.....there only one option install more tools and features

Comment: i share visual studio installer image in my question

Comment: @patelvinay that is the visual studio. We're talking about VisualStudioInstaller that is  a project extension to create a Setup Installer of your application. You have to download that: [This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) and follow the steps of my answer... Visual Studio Installer is different of VisualStudioInstaller Project Extension.

Comment: oh sorry i don't know this before....and currently i tried your solution

Comment: I don't see any option to "Create New Shortcut to Primary Output".

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron Right Click on "User's Desktop" And you have Create Shortcut to Primary Output in there

Comment: @Mikev I don't have that option, but it's ok, I'll use a different Setup creator. I used one not from Microsoft before and quite liked it.

Answer (score 7):

You must be install "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension from visual studio extensions menu. This process need after Visual Studio 2017.

Extension link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Answer (score 2):

On visual Studio 2019,

Go to Extensions > Manage Extensions > Online > Search, find, download, and install "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension.