# Setup only works in one session/with one user

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I created a WindowsForms app, followed by a setup with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541199/how-to-create-setup-exe-file-for-window-form-application-in-visual-studio-2019). However, I can only set it up on my main session. When I try to connect with another user, it launches the setup, but when I double-click on the app, it doesn't show. Is there a solution to my problem?

Also, I don't want to have to copy the app files into each user's machine (I put the whole folder including both the app and the wizard in a shared folder between all users).

I tried installing it from the shared folder, and also after copying the setup folder, without it working.
Here are both parts where I suspected an issue, but they're not behind it.

```
 string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            label21.Text = userName;
            string username = "";
            for(int i = 8; i < userName.Length; i++)
            {
                username += userName[i];
            }
            string filename = $"C:/Users/{username}/Desktop/fichier.xlsx";
```

and

```
if ((isEmpty == true) && (radioButton4.Checked == false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Due to one or more cells being empty, the file was not saved.");
            }
            else
            {
                wb.SaveAs($"C:/Users/{username}/Downloads/Controle{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}.xlsx");
            }
```

Comment: Most likely you're relying on hard-coded paths instead of looking up the correct locations from the system environment, so when the app starts up it can't find needed fails and quits right away. It works from your main session because it's the same user account, so the hard-coded paths are still correct. But without a lot more info we can't know for sure.

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: Without seeing any code? I couldn't begin to tell you where to look. But start by searching for any strings in the code starting with "C:\Users". That's usually a sign you've made a mistake.

Comment: Oh! I understand. I did indeed put an excel file in a shared (to a smaller scope) folder. I'll try seeing that, otherwise I'll post the code.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what to show, because my code has nothing to do with it. I looked up the system environment locations, but nothing changes

Comment: I think what you're going to need is some stacktrace information to get you on the right path in the whole troubleshooting. Can you run the code as the different user from visual studio? That should give you some stacktrace info to add to your original post. With that we can help guide you better to a solution

Comment: I'll go try that and change my post whatever the result.

Comment: @Jonathan the code didn't work at first because my database was local. might that be it?

Comment: Not sure which database you're talking about, you haven't mentioned one in the question. But it's likely, depending on what the database holds.

Also, in your question you mention `user machines`, do you not test this on a single machine with different users? Or is it tested on different machines completely?

Comment: I test it on the same machine, but with different users. Also sorry if I'm not being very clear, it's my first time using all these tools in a practical way.

Comment: Ok, that eliminates a few possible issues. I would still like to see some stacktrace. Have you been able to run the code in visual studio as another user to see the console for any stacktrace logs? (I'm assuming you no longer try to access files from other users)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-7.0#system-environment-getfolderpath(system-environment-specialfolder)) to get the correct paths every time.

```
let desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

etc.

Comment: I'll definitely try that, thanks for your help. Do you think it also has to do with why I can't open the app with another user in my machine? Also what is specialfolder in this case?

Comment: This change generates a "Empty extension" error

Comment: @LiterallyGutsFromBerserk Other users don't have any access to files stored in the profile folder belonging to your user. In that case, even if you find the right path, opening the file will fail for security reasons.

Comment: That's why I added `string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`. Or is that not the right method to use.

Comment: @LiterallyGutsFromBerserk No, that is not correct, because Windows lets you put your profile folder anywhere. Also, if the file was not deployed with the application and only lives on your profile, having the other user lookup their own name won't help.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: What are you trying to _do_ in the end? Of course you can configure an installer to ship more than one file, or you can embed them as resources, or whatever.

Comment: I just want the installer to work on all sessions/users*

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish but would it work to use a more generic folder such as `Program data` to store and work with your files for the app? That way all users would be able to access them.

Comment: @Jonathan I published the app, and then copied the published folder to the other user's session using a shared directory, but it doesn't do anything.